# how to replace \ with / using java script string functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, replace

I have image path like this

```
var str = "D:\Poc\testProject\DataPush\public\unzip\cust\AccountData\2.jpg"
```

this string throw error shown in image. but when i remove unzip with extract it's work fine don't know why??
[image]

but when i do it's work fine but new issue start

```
var str = "D:\Poc\testProject\DataPush\public\extract\cust\AccountData\2.jpg"
```

when i use `replace` function of java script it's show result of below image.

[image]

basically i want output like this from above string.

```
D:/Poc/testProject/DataPush/public/extract/cust/AccountData/2.jpg
```

As suggested in remove testProject output is same for `str.replace('/\/g','/')`

```
var str = D:\Poc\DataPush\public\extract\cust\AccountData\2.jpg
```

output is

```
str.replace('/\\/g','/')
"D:PocDataPushpublicextractcustAccountData.jpg"
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is, that your path is actually `D:Poc[TAB]estProjectDataPushpublicunzipcustAccountData2.jpg`, escape the backslashes with another backslash.

Comment: What is said above stands for the exact example in the question. If you're getting the path from an external source, the backslashes are probably correct. Then you can do a simple replacement: `str = str.replace(/\\/g, '/');`. After your edit: `'/\\/g'` is not a RegExp, drop the quotes.

Comment: Please avoid pasting images into your questions if it's possible to simply paste the text that appears in the image. The text provides advantages like being easier for us to read, being possible to copy/paste, and being accessible to screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

```js
var stringReplaced = String.raw`D:\Poc\testProject\DataPush\public\unzip\cust\AccountData\2.jpg`.split('\\').join('/')
console.log(stringReplaced);
```